# Joomla 3.1 how to open tagged web links in new tab?

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, tags

I use joomla 3.1.1 and i have created a compact list of tagged items menu item to display weblinks by tags.
The problem is that when I click on a weblink on that list the linked page opens in the same browser tab. The links themselves open in a new tab if I display them normally.
Is there a way to make the links open in a new tab? It doesn't seem to be any option there.
Using the compact list of tagged items solves other issues so I would like to keep it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check your weblinks module.

Make sure **Target Window** is **Open in new window**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I apologize for this delayed response. All my weblinks are set to open in a new window when I display then normally. The problem here is that my weblinks are tagged and I use compact list of tagged items menu items to display them by tags. These lists work like the list of articles and open the linked page in the same window. What I want to know is how can i make a compact list of tagged items to open in a new window.